# `awk`-ing plain text tables produced by pandoc with fields/cells/values that contain spaces

Tags: bash, shell, awk, pandoc

I've run into this problem a number of times and maybe it's just my unsophisticated technique as I'm still a bit of a novice with the finer points of text processing, but using `pandoc` going from `html` to `plain` yields pretty tables in the form of:

```
 #   IP Address          Device Name             MAC Address
--- ------------- -------------------------- -------------------
 1   192.168.1.3   ANDROID-FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF   FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF
 2   192.168.1.4           XXXXXXX            FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF
 3   192.168.1.5              --              FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF
 4   192.168.1.6              --              FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF
--- ------------- -------------------------- -------------------
```

The column headings here in this example (and the fields/cells/whatever in others) aren't especially `awk` friendly since they contain spaces. There must be some utility (or `pandoc` option) to add delimiters or otherwise process it in a smart and simple way to make it easier to use with `awk` (since the dash ruling hints as the max column width), but I'm fast approaching the limits of my knowledge and have been unable to find any good solutions on my own. I'd appreciate any help and I'm open to alternate approaches (I just use `pandoc` since that's what I know).

Comment: Try `ssconvert` - comes with gnumeric.

Comment: If you use gawk, you can use fixed width fields with `FIELDWIDTHS`, see [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Fixed-width-data).

Comment: if not using `gawk` and FIELDWIDTHS, then just `col1=substr($0,1,3) ; col2=subtr($0,5,13);...printf("%s|%s\n",col1,col2)}` Good luck!

Comment: If you want to create an "awk-friendly" file from html, you could also use `xmlstarlet`

Answer (score 2):

I've got a solution for you which parses the dash line to get column lengths, then uses that info to divide each line into columns (similar to what @shellter proposed in the comment, but without the need to hardcode values).

First, within the `BEGIN` block we read the headers line and the dashes line.  Then we will grab the column lengths by splitting the dashline and processing it.

```
BEGIN {
    getline headers
    getline dashline

    col_count = split(dashline, columns, " ")
    for (i=1;i<=col_count;i++)
        col_lens[i] = length(columns[i])
}
```

Now we have the lengths of each column and you can use that inside the main body.

```
{
    start = 1
    for (i=start;i<=col_count;i++){ 
        col_n = substr($0, start, col_lens[i])
        start = start + col_lens[i] + 1
        printf("column %i: [%s]\n",i,col_n);
    }
}
```

That seems a little onerous, but it works.  I believe this answers your question.  To make things a little nicer, I factored out the line parsing into a [user defined function](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/awk/awk_user_defined_functions.htm).  That's convenient because you can now use it on the headers you stored (if you want).

Here's the complete solution:

```
function parse_line(line, col_lens, col_count){
    start = 1
    for (i=start;i<=col_count;i++){
        col_i = substr(line, start, col_lens[i])
        start = start + col_lens[i] + 1
        printf("column %i: [%s]\n", i, col_i)
    }
}    
BEGIN { 
        getline headers
        getline dashline
        col_count = split(dashline, columns, " ")
        for (i=1;i<=col_count;i++){
            col_lens[i] = length(columns[i])
        }

        parse_line(headers, col_lens, col_count);
}
{
        parse_line($0, col_lens, col_count);
}
```

If you put your example table into a file called `table` and this program into a file called `dashes.awk`, here's the output (using `head -n -1` to drop the final row of dashes):

```
$ head -n -1 table | awk -f dashes.awk 
column 1: [ # ]
column 2: [ IP Address  ]
column 3: [       Device Name        ]
column 4: [    MAC Address]
column 1: [ 1 ]
column 2: [ 192.168.1.3 ]
column 3: [ ANDROID-FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF ]
column 4: [ FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF]
column 1: [ 2 ]
column 2: [ 192.168.1.4 ]
column 3: [         XXXXXXX          ]
column 4: [ FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF]
column 1: [ 3 ]
column 2: [ 192.168.1.5 ]
column 3: [            --            ]
column 4: [ FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF]
column 1: [ 4 ]
column 2: [ 192.168.1.6 ]
column 3: [            --            ]
column 4: [ FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF]
```

Comment: Neat, but there will always be corner cases like "what if a table entry consists of all dashes?"

Comment: @tripleee I think that as long as the table contains that row of dashes separated by spaces, it doesn't matter what's in the table cells.  The second row of the table sets the column widths, after that we're just grabbing substrings of those lengths from `$0`.  I'm not saying this is very elegant, but I think it works given the table format shown in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at pandoc's [filter](https://pandoc.org/filters.html) functionallity: It allows you to programmatically alter the document without having to parse the table yourself.  Probably the simplest option is to use [lua-filters](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html), as those require no external program and are fully platform-independent.

Here is a filter which acts on each cell of the table body, ignoring the table header:

```
function Table (table)
  for i, row in ipairs(table.rows) do
    for j, cell in ipairs(row) do
      local cell_text = pandoc.utils.stringify(pandoc.Div(cell))
      local text_val = changed_cell(cell_text)
      row[j] = pandoc.read(text_val).blocks
    end
  end
  return table
end
```

where `changed_cell` could be either a lua function (lua has good [built-in support for patterns](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.gsub)) or a function which pipes the output through awk:

```
function changed_cell (raw_text)
  return pandoc.pipe('awk', {'YOUR AWK SCRIPT'}, raw_text)
end
```

The above is a slightly unidiomatic pandoc filter, as filters usually don't act on raw strings but on pandoc AST elements. However, the above should work fine in your case.